# Remove line spacing while copying from MS Word to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to know how to remove spacing between lines while copying from MS Word to Wordpress editor.

From the source code I see that every line is wrapped in a `<p>` tag.

But when I paste in the Text editor it does it correctly, `<p>` tags on the paragraph and `<br>` tags whenever necessary. I cannot do this however since I want to preserve some of the Word formatting.

This is the format I want,

```
<p>
para 1 line 1
<br>
para 1 line 2
<br>
para 1 line 3
<br>
para 1 line 4
</p>

<p>
para 2 line 1
<br>
para 2 line 2
<br>
para 2 line 3
<br>
para 2 line 4
</p>
```

Is there anyway I can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Hie Vinith, maybe you can try the "Clean the format" button in your tool bar. This is an eraser at the fifth position after the text format field on the second line, beginning from the left.

Or you can try the "Paste a text" button, just on the left of the "Clean the format button" it allows you to paste any text without any formating.

Comment: I loose some of the Word formatting when I do that @Paul.

Comment: If everything works whent you paste it in your text editor, you can paste from word to your text editor and then copy from your text edito and paste it in the text edit of your wordpress content